# How to get rid of "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled" in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

How to get rid of  "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled" in WCF

My objective is to display a home page at the default url.
PFB my code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileHost
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{filename=null}")]
    Stream Files(string filename);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}

public class Service1 : IFileHost
{
    public System.IO.Stream Files(string filename)
    {
        string rattex;
        if (filename==""||string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            rattex = "home";
        }
        else
        {
            rattex = "<html><body>" + filename + "</body></html>";
        }
        StreamReader ret = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rattex)));
        Stream stream = ret.BaseStream;
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";

        //Set the correct context type for the file requested.

        return stream;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8434/";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFileHost), new  WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior()  );

        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is running");
        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

I want get rid of this page and get a home page for null string
[image]

Comment: Have you actually read the error page, it tells you exactly what's wrong, including the steps to follow to fix it

Comment: I think no one understood my qs. I said I dont want this page. I want the service to return home when there is no /{filename}. ie when raw url is accessed, it should still call the service with null input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a metadata endpoint to your service.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738489%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on how to do that programatically.

Comment: I dont need this stuff. My objective is to create   my own webserver.